# Odoo - How to update a pre defined DATE field value

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to modify hr.contract model so the '`end_date`' field gets the value of '`effective_date`' which is in another model '`resignation_application`'.
The concept is when an employee fill a resignation application it updates the contract end date.

Here's my code:

```
class resignation_application(osv.osv):
    _name = 'resignation.application'
    _columns = {
        'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', "Employee", select=True, invisible=False, readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)], 'confirm':[('readonly',False)]}),
        'effective_date': fields.date('Effective Date', readonly=True, states={'draft':[('readonly',False)], 'confirm':[('readonly',False)]}, select=True, copy=False),

class hr_contract(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'hr.contract'
     _columns = {         
        'end_date': fields.date('End Date', compute= '_compute_effective_date', store=True),        

    }

    @api.model
    def create(self, values):        
        if 'end_date' in values and not values['end_date']:
            del(values['end_date'])
        return super(hr_contract, self).create(values)

    @api.one
    @api.depends('end_date','employee_id')
    def _compute_effective_date(self):
        recs = self.env['resignation.application'] # retrieve an instance of MODEL
        recs = recs.search([('state', '=', 'validate')]) # search returns a recordset
        for rec in recs: # iterate over the records
            if self.employee_id == rec.employee_id:
                self.end_date = rec.effective_date
        return recs.write({'end_date': rec.effective_date})
```

But it didn't return the end date.. I know there's something wrong with my return statement but I don't know how to fix it.. Also I want to add an inverse method to `end_date` field so the hr officer can add an end date to the employee contract. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are mixing v8 (decorators) and v7 (osv.osv and _columns) stuffs.

Besides, in v8 you don't need to return anything nor write directly the `end_date` field in the compute method, but just set the field as you already did. Did you try to just remove the return statement?

Comment: I tried it without the return statement, but it requires me to fill a resignation form and get approved  before you make an employee contract which isn't happening in the real scenario.. I mean the `end_date` field isn't updated in the same moment that effective date was validated